# object 'plotp' not found whilst loading namespace 'rms'

Tags: r

I am trying to load the rms library but I keep getting this error message:

```
object 'plotp' not found whilst loading namespace 'rms'
```

I installed rms with dependencies. I appreciate the help.

Thanks.

Comment: I had a similar problem today (while trying to run rms::lrm), but managed to resolve it by updating package Hmisc to version 4.2.0 (published 2019-01-26) and rms to version 5.1-3 (published 2019-01-27).

Comment: TThx @JWilliman, that worked for me too.

Answer (score 11):

Converting @JWilliman's comment to an answer:

`install.packages(c("Hmisc", "rms"))`

Which should update:

- Package `Hmisc` to 4.2.0 (published 2019-01-26) or greater/later
- Package `rms` to 5.1-3 (published 2019-01-27) or greater/later

Comment: This saved me a big-time, as `rms` [DESCRIPTION](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/harrelfe/rms/4e2cb79eff984911b5c36b17f529ee85a134da9b/DESCRIPTION) file wrongly stated that it depends on `Hmisc (>= 4.1-0)`.