# Loading 'lordif' package issues due to load failure for 'rms' package

Tags: r

I'm trying to use the lordif package in R which has worked on my mac computer and every other computer in the past. I've just switched to a windows dell computer and had to install the package again but not able to because unable to load `rms` package (`object 'plotp' not found`) even though I was able to successfully install that package. Full error:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rms’:
object 'plotp' not found whilst loading namespace 'rms'
```

I've updated my version of R to the latest one (3.5.2). I've uninstalled and reinstalled rms and lordif package. I get successful installation messages for rms but when I try to load it or lordif I get that error message.

```
library(rms)
library(lordif)

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rms’: 
object 'plotp' not found whilst loading namespace 'rms'
```

Comment: I had a similar problem today (while trying to run `rms::lrm`), but managed to resolve it by updating package `Hmisc` to version 4.2.0 (published 2019-01-26) and `rms` to version 5.1-3 (published 2019-01-27).

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54446860/object-plotp-not-found-whilst-loading-namespace-rms

Comment: That worked! Thanks so much